# docker-compose: reinitializing MySQL db every time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

We have a Rails app with MySQL as DB. The `db` part of `docker-compose.yml` looks like

```
  db:
    image: mysql
    env_file:
      - ma.env
    volumes:
      - ./dump-db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
            - MYSQL_HOST=
```

and under `./dump-db` folder there actually is an sql-dump of our db.

Problem is, we need to have that exact dump loaded each and every time `docker-compose up` is run. MySQL docker image works in such a way, that it stores it's data on host machine and therefore your db-service is not stateless.

**What we need** is that `db` service discarded all changes done within `docker-compose up` previous run and fresh-started with that exact dump.

Comment: Make your own container derived from the mysql official.   Or roll your own custom mysql.  Or have your rails app bootstrap mysql.  Or make a new container that only bootstraps your mysql.    Or use rails seeds.   Or...

Comment: I think this is write. Customize the image to do what you want (not use a volume for the data store).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED

actually, ideas above gave me some insight to RTM and here goes

- Get your own MySQL Dockerfile
- Remove the VOLUME line from it, where 
  it mentions that `/var/lib/mysql` should be mounted on host.
- `docker-compose up --force-recreate db`

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to keep the data each time that you execute the `docker-compose up` you have to remove the volumes created by the execution of this command.

To achieve that you can execute the following command, that will remove the `db` service with the volumes declared in the `volumes` section.

> docker-compose down -v db

Comment: thanks! but is there a way to convince `docker-compose`  to automatically kill volumes?

Comment: That command is wrong. `down` doesn't take positional arguments. You can do `docker-compose down -v` or `docker-compose rm -v db`.